# Dcucumber.options, run a single cucumber test

Tags: java, maven, junit, cucumber

I have to following project structure:

The directory **src/test/java/ic/tests** contains junit tests and the directory **src/test/features/ic** contains cucumber test (feature files).

But when I do a maven run (**mvn test -Dcucumber.options="src/test/features/ic --tags @IC-115**") to execute a single cucumber test the executor starts the junit tests in the **src/test/java/ic/tests** directory...

Only the corresponding feature file is annotated with **@IC-115**.

Even the absolute version **mvn test -Dcucumber.options="C:\Users_Clemens_\Documents\test-ic\src\test\resources\features\ic\IC-115-LogOut.feature"** does not execute my test.

How can I execute the single cucumber test that I want to execute?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could solve it by adding a runner class AND moved feature files to "src/test/resources" AND added the maven-surefire-plugin with adding an exclusion to the runner class. Seems like these 3 steps are all necessary.

```
package kiwigrid;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/resources")
public class Runner {

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the command with the name of the feature (exact way to the feature).

mvn test -Dcucumber.options="src/test/features/ic/FeatureName.feature"

Or if the feature is composed by more than one test you could set a specific(not used  for others scenarios) tag to the test and run with

`mvn verify -Dcucumber.options="--tags @specifictag"`

Comment: I did it with specific tag like you see above...seems not working

Comment: Even with filename is not working...it executes every time the junit tests.

Comment: Could you paste a screenshot from your cmd(Eingabeaufforderung) to see what happens when you run it with specific tag (please make sure you run the command in the project's directory)

Comment: see new screenshot above

Comment: Ok, obviously you still run it with the old tag (@IC-115). Could you go to features-> ic -> 'the feature we are looking for'and place a tag  @run  before the name of the scenario that must be runned. After that you could run in the cmd the following command -> mvn verify -Dcucumber.options="--tags @run"

Comment: that does not any difference if I change the name of the tag to (@run). (@IC-115) is already before the name of the scenario

Comment: One scenario could have more than one tag. So you could just add the tag run next to the tag IC-115 in the scenario that you would like to run. The goal here is to have only one tag (as you said the tag IC-115 exists also in src/test/java/ic/tests  and you don't want to run it) that is not repeated and to point this tag in the command.

Comment: IC-115 only exist in one specific test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155946/discussion-between-mr-cas-and-gartenkralle).

Comment: I think there's a typo in the command, it should be `tag` not `tags`.